# "Allow from all" and "Options –Indexes" is Illegal option?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have this .htaccess configuration

```
allow from all
Options –Indexes
```

and I want is the my web clients can access my resources in that folder but they can't do a directory listing...

did i went to something wrong?

this is my error in my error log

> D:/xampp/htdocs/mysite/themes/graymatter/js/.htaccess: Illegal option
>   \xe2\x80\x93Indexes, referer: http://localhost/mysite/site/index

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using an actual hyphen (-) instead of that en dash.